# Dynamic path for cachedir when placing system folder above web root

Tags: config, system

I've got a query about setting the cachedir path in system/config/database.php when placing the system folder above web root.

When the system folder isn't above web root, I'd normally set the path like this:

```
$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = "${_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/my_system/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/";
```

But when the system folder is placed above web root, what dynamic path should I be using instead? Thanks.

Edit: In fact, does anyone know the purpose of this cachedir? I've checked a few sites and I've got nothing stored at this folder location anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for this in the [Webunder EE2 config template repository](https://bitbucket.org/webunder/ee2_config_template):

```
$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = APPPATH."cache/db_cache/";
```